# How to find and replace a string in HTML DOM element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've tried to replace occurences of string `"blue"` with `"red"` in the document using DOM methods. However, I have not got the desired result.

Here's the code I've tried:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Click the button to replace "blue" with "red" in the paragraph below:</p>
    <div id="main">
      <p>Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.</p>
      <p>Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.</p>
    </div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var str = document.getElementById("main");
        var x = str.document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        var res = x.innerHTML.replace(/blue/gi, "red");
        document.getElementsByTagName("p").innerHTML = res;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList; you need to loop.

Comment: X is not an object, but it is an array of objects in the page. please use `x[0].innerHTML`. yes, it should be a loop. just gave an example how it can be updated...

Comment: @Murtaza I think this should loop to change 'blue'.

Comment: i have used x[0].innerHTML still not working. I am a beginner to java script. Could you please explain what is a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code.

To get `p`s from the `div`, you need to:

```js
str.getElementsByTagName("p");  // and not str.document...
```

The above statement will return a collection and not a single element. So you need to loop over the collection and do your replace.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var res = x[i].innerHTML.replace(/blue/gi, "red");
    x[i].innerHTML = res;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/XP9Nr/).

Update based on your comment <sup><sup>(what is a loop)</sup></sup>:
Please use the tutorials [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to ignore the `p` tags altogether and just do the replacement on the `div`'s `innerHTML`, like so:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("main");
    var inner = str.innerHTML;
    var res = inner.replace(/blue/gi, "red");
    str.innerHTML = res;
}
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <p>Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.</p>
  <p>Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.</p>
</div>
<button>Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```js
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
    paras[i].textContent = paras[i].textContent.replace(/blue/g,'red');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. You can't call `.document` on `str`, which is already an object.
2. You'll need to iterate through the array of `p` elements, which you were *almost* grabbing correctly. :)

Something like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("main");
    var x = str.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var text = x[i].innerHTML;
        x[i].innerHTML = text.replace(/blue/gi, "red");
    }    
}
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/a942G/

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList; you need to loop, using a `for` loop for example. But here's an alternative more re-usable approach that handles letter case:

```
// helper to convert NodeList to real array
var toArray = Array.call.bind([].slice)
// helper to query the DOM
var query = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)

// uppercase first letter
var capitalize = function(x) {
  return x[0].toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)
}
// replace word and handle letter case
var replaceWord = function(word, replacement, str) {
  return str.replace(RegExp(word, 'gi'), function(m) {
    return /[A-Z]/.test(m) ? capitalize(replacement) : replacement
  })
}

// query all `p` tags and replace
toArray(query('p')).forEach(function(x) {
  x.textContent = replaceWord('blue', 'red', x.textContent)
})
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/siveh/2/edit